# value update in firestore using cloud function show before and after update documents in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

you need to replace before value with after update value.

however my scenario is:

the following ui is from flutter. if you use `cloud function` to update a given document. The following scenario occur.

[image]

below lines of code is what i have used to show values in ui like in image above.

```dart
_firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userID)
        .collection("bought")
        .doc(_boughtId)
        .collection('invoice')
        // .where("userId", isEqualTo: userID)
        //? not  required coz userDoc has it
        /*  .doc(userID)
        .collection("note") */
        // .orderBy('serverTimeStamp', descending: true)
        .where("buyerUserId", isEqualTo: userID)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .limit(10)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
```

above is flutter code is what i have used for firestore in flutter

below is cloud function javascript used to update.

```js
                admin
                .firestore()
                .collection("users").doc(change.after.data().sellerUserId)
                .collection("sold")
                .doc(change.after.data().sellerUserId + "-" + change.after.data().buyerUserId)
                .update({

                    total: FieldValue.increment(
                        change.after.data().total
                    ),
                    updatedAt: change.after.data().createdAt,
                  

                })
```

if you want to recreate what i have built you have to use `ListView.builder`.
the document takes `25` as `total`. other field wont be required to recreate the scenario.

however you will need to trigger update function from `cloudfunciton`. you can use `onCreate` wehre your document will be updated as soon as its created.
You will see the **peculiar** behaviour occur.

the replacement need to make user interface without repeated values. only then user can experience a normal behaviour from the application.

Comment: Hi, is the issue resolved?

Comment: Whats exactly the issue you are facing?